# WSO2 Identity Server SCIM API Internationalization

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using **WSO2 Identity Server SCIM APIs** for user management(i.e creating,listing,updating and authenticating users) in our application.We are also using **WSO2 API Manager token API** for fetching access token.Our application supports internationalization and we have to display error messages recieved as response from the above mentioned APIs in the localized language.

**Does WSO2 support localization** for these APIs? If so, is there any reference link to help with the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently WSO2 IS/APIM does not support API level localization. Only UI level localization[1] is supported.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Internationalization+and+Localization